# Let $f:G \rightarrow G $ be given by $f(a)=a^{-1} $. Prove that $f$ is a bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

Let *G* be a group, then by the group axioms we have that:

$(\forall a\in G)(\exists a^{-1}\in G)(a * a^{-1} = e = a^{-1} * a) $ where e is the identity element.

For a function to be bijective it must be one-to-one and onto. 
Is it enough to just state that since there exists an inverse for every element *a* the function *f* is onto, and since inverses are unique it is one-to-one?

Comment: Because inverses are unique, this function is well-defined.

Comment: and because $f(a^{-1})=a$, this is surjection (or "onto").

Answer (score 1):

If $f(a)=e$, then $a^{-1}=e$ and thus $a=a(aa^{-1})=a^2e=a^2$. If $a = a^2$ in any group, we must have $a=e$, because $e= a^{-1}a = a^{-1}a^2 = a$. Hence $f$ is injective, because $Ker(f) = \{e\}$. Given $ b \in G$, we have $f(b^{-1}) = (b^{-1})^{-1} = b$. Therefore $f$ is bijective.